# Python: How to import package root with relative imports

Tags: python, import

I have a large number of names defined in the top-level __init__.py of a python package. I would like to use a *relative* import to import this namespace because I do not necessarily know the package name at runtime (it might even be used as a sub-package of some other package). For example, take the following package:

```
my_package/
    __init__.py
        a = 1
        b = 2
        ...
    my_module.py
        from . import ??? as my_package
        print(my_package.a)
```

How shall I fix the import statement in my_module such that the print statement works correctly? I would also rather avoid `from . import a, b, ...`; I just want the entire package namespace imported as one variable.

I have tried `from . import __init__ as my_package`, but in this case `my_package` is imported as a method-wrapper, not a module. I have also tried `my_module = __import__(__package__)`, which works only in the case that my_package is not a sub-package.

It seems like there should be a simple answer to this..

Comment: Why do you need to put that code in `__init__.py` instead of just making it a separate module?

Comment: Just for convenience--many symbols throughout the package are imported to the top-level to make them easily available. I suppose I could also do the same set of imports to a sub-module, but that seems like a silly fix (but perhaps the problem is equally silly).

Comment: `__init__.py` file is rare place where `from submodule import *` might be appropriate if you want to make all public names from submodule to be directly accessible on your package too. As @BrenBarn said, just put it into a separate module then you could use `from . import submodule` in my_module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `__package__` to know the package name, and [`importlib.import_module`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module); This works for sub-packages.

```
import importlib
pkg = importlib.import_module(__package__)
print(pkg.a)
```

Comment: @BrenBarn, Thank yo for comment. I updated the answer to use `import.import_module`.

Comment: Thanks, this works well (although BrenBarn and shx2 make a compelling argument to avoid this situation in the first place).

Comment: @Luke, I agree with them.

Answer (score 1):

`__init__.py` is used for names you want to expose as being importable from the top level of your package. In this case, you're using it for importing names internally, i.e. within your package, hence the problem.

So, you should put all the names/definitions to be used internally in your package in another file, e.g. `defs.py`, and import from there:

```
from .defs import foo, bar, baz
```

And make sure to only leave in `__init__.py` the names you want to top-level-expose to the outside world.

EDIT: to clarify, in `__init__.py`, you don't need to duplicate the names/definitions, simply import them in exactly the same way:

```
from .defs import foo, bar
```

Or

```
from .defs import *  # not recommended, of course
```

Then, from outside the package, names can be imported from packege's top level like this:

```
from my_package import foo, bar
```

Or

```
from path.to.my_package import foo, bar
```

Comment: The names in \__init__.py _are_ meant to be publicly visible, but some internal modules benefit from having access to the same merged namespace (to avoid otherwise very lengthy blocks of import statements). I could certainly duplicate the merged namespace in an internal module, but it sure seems like I should be able to import the top-level namespace.

Comment: @Luke: You can import the top-level namespace, but you need to know its name (i.e., the package name).

Comment: I have not been able to achieve that in tests where the "top-level" is actually a sub-package of some larger package. The sub-package name seems to be absent from the parent-package namespace at the time of import.

Comment: @Luke: Well, then it's not the top level! :-)  I'm not quite sure what situation you're describing, although it's true that modules in a package aren't automatically loaded if you just import the package.  So if you do `import pkg` then `pkg.module` will fail unless you actually do `import pkg.module` or the like.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware there's not a way to import a package's `__init__.py` as a module using a relative import.

If you have various general objects in the package and your goal is (as you said in the comment) "to make them easily available", just put them in their own module.  `from . import miscPackageStuff` isn't really any less convenient than `from . import __init__` (if you could do that).

If you also want these general objects to be accessible externally without explicitly importing the submodule, just do `from .miscPackageStuff import foo, bar, baz` in `__init__.py`.

Comment: The convenience is for external users; the names in \__init__.py are meant to be publicly visible, but some internal modules benefit from having access to the same large namespace (to avoid otherwise very lengthy blocks of import statements).

Comment: @Luke: Then just import the submodule from within `__init__.py`.