# Python package confusion; from package import *

Tags: python, module

I'm developing a Flask application with following structure:

```
src
├── config.yaml
├── requirements.txt
├── run.py
└── vortex
    ├── db.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── models
    │   ├── computer.py
    │   ├── image.py # Contains a class named Image
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── templates
    │   └── ...
    └── views.py
```

`modals/__init__.py`:

```
from .computer import Computer
from .image import Image
```

`modals/computer.py`:

```
from vortex.models import *

i = Image(...)
```

But somehow, I can't access Image class in `modals/computer.py`, but the documentation says, if I don't use `__all__`; all the names defined in `__init__.py` should be imported. Is that resulting to a cyclic import would be a problem?

What am I doing wrong, and how can I use all classes defined in models in other parts of the program?

Edit:

The traceback:

```
  ...
  File "..../src/vortex/models/computer.py", line 35, in image
    return Image.find_by_id(self._fields.image)
NameError: global name 'Image' is not defined
```

Comment: Did you really name your file `init.py`?  As your quote from the documentation shows, the name must be `__init__.py`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, typo. Fixed.

Comment: What is the error message you get?  Also, you say `Image` is in image.py but then you say you can't access it in computer.py.  Do both modules have an Image class?

Comment: I added the traceback to the question and I'm sorry for my bad English. You are right that Image is in image.py, I want to import that Image class into computer py with bulk import(`from vortex.models import *`).

Answer (score 0):

If you are in `computer.py` and want to import something else from within the same package, just use a relative import:

```
from .image import Image
```

If you want to be able to import a bunch of stuff in one place, make a file `allModels.py` with your imports, then do `from .allModels import *`.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20726736/python-how-to-import-package-root-with-relative-imports/20726785#20726785) for info about how/why it's awkward to import `__init__.py` relatively.

Comment: I know, bulk imports are discouraged, but that would be really easier for me to just import all of the models. Also, I also want to do `from models import *` in views.py too.

Comment: I want to achieve the same behaviour as `concurrents.future` default module, look at its `__init__.py`. I just want a way to do a `from models import *` and access `Image` and `Computer` classes.